# Shift texts rightwards instead of vertical scroll in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with height suppose **200px**. I am showing some data inside that div. I want to show the data like this :

> A  E  I
>
> B  F  J
>
> C  G  K
>
> D  H  L
>
> -----------------------------**this height is 200px**

I don't want any vertical scroll bar . I mean after certain height the data will shift rightwards and again start from the top .

> I have used `column-count` property , but it is not working as I want
>   .

Can anyone please suggest ?

My CSS looks like this :

```
.mydivclass {
    height: 200px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-height:200px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using flexbox on the parent

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

## example

```css
.mydivclass {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  height: 200px;
  width: 0;
}

/* just some styling 
  --------------------- */
.mydivclass * {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
 
  color: white;
  background: blue; 
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydivclass ">
  
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
  <span>D</span>
  
  <span>E</span>
  <span>F</span>
  <span>G</span>
  <span>H</span>
  
  <span>I</span>
  <span>J</span>
  <span>K</span>
  <span>L</span>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `<br />` element after adding 3 items on each row. Or with php for exmaple, create a counter and after adding 3 items of data, reset the counter and add a break-element. You could even consider using a table, but that highly depends on the data you want to show

Comment: Actually the length of data is not fixed .